# Passing a list from an imported module

Tags: python, list, module, scipy, python-import

I have a file with a function defined, which imports and organizes data into a list of lists. It returns that list of lists, and this all functions fine within the same file (if I write a main function and call the import function, no problems).

```
def import_viscosity_data(size_of_header):
    ...
    return (list_of_lists)
```

I'm trying to call this function from another file in the same directory, using the following:

```
import load_files
print(load_files.import_viscosity_data(7))
```

Unfortunately, this keeps returning 'None', and if I try to get the length of the returned array, it throws an error:TypeError: object of type 'NoneType' has no len()

I'm guessing that it's passing me a reference to the list, and the actual list gets deleted as soon as the function terminates, but I'm not sure how to resolve this problem. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Here's the code:

```
import os
import tkinter
from tkinter import filedialog
#import decimal
from decimal import *

def import_viscosity_data(size_of_header):
    ### This function imports viscosity data from multiple files, skipping the 
    ### header passed inof the form shearRate '\t' viscosity and puts it into 
    ### an array of the form test_num[result_type[data]]] where result type 
    ### is 0 (shearRate) or 1 (viscosity)

    header_size = size_of_header

    root = tkinter.Tk()
    root.withdraw()

    file_path = root.tk.splitlist(filedialog.askopenfilenames(
        parent=root, title='Choose a file(s):'))

    test_num = []
    result_type = []
    data_1 = []
    data_2 = []

    for file_name in file_path:

        f = open(file_name)

        ## Skip the header, which consists of header_size lines
        for i in range(header_size):
            next(f)

        lines = [line.strip() for line in f]
        f.close()


        ## For a line, slice all characters before the tab, then after the tab
        ## convert to Decimal, and append to the data list
        for index in range(len(lines)):
            data_1.append(Decimal(lines[index][0:lines[index].find('\t')]))
            data_2.append(Decimal(lines[index][lines[index].find('\t') + 1:]))

        result_type.append(data_1)
        result_type.append(data_2)

        test_num.append(result_type)
        data_1, data_2, result_type = [], [], []

    return(test_num)
```

Here's some sample data to try it on (any data in 2 columns with a tab in between):

```
0   1.2381
0.004   1.23901
0.008   1.23688
0.012   1.23734
0.016   1.23779
0.02    1.23901
0.024   1.23932
0.028   1.23886
0.032   1.23688
0.036   1.2384
```

Again, within this program (running in an IDE, or if I write a small main() function), this returns a list of list of lists, and works just fine. However, when I import the function in a different file, it returns None, without throwing any errors. The function name pops up automatically in the IDE after the `import load_files`, so it seems to be importing properly.

*Note*
*This secondary problem was resolved. The file `load_files.py` was within a directory called `load_files`. The import statement was changed to `from load_files import load_files` and it now functions properly.*

Today my problem has gotten even worse. Now, I can't get any functions from the first file to be recognized in the second. Even a simple set of code like:

```
#load_files.py
def test_func():
    print('test successful')

#test.py
import load_files
load_files.test_func()
```

is throwing this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\tmulholland\Documents\Carreau - WLF\test.py", line 8, in <module>
    load_files.test_func
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'test_func'
```

`load_files.py` is in it's own folder (of the same name) with a blank `__init__.py` file

*Note* I should add that I'm using the Pyzo IDE because I want to use the scipy library to do curve fitting / optimization problems. I can't get any functions to import correctly today into Pyzo, no matter how simple. Has anybody else had this problem?

Comment: No, that's not how Python works. Please show us more code; something else is wrong. If you are not returning `None` explicitly, it could also be that your function ends without an explicit `return` *at all* and that means the default is to return `None` instead.

Comment: the import_viscosity_data function is long, but rest assured it returns a proper list of lists. For instance, if I put a issue a call to the function, using an IDE, within the load_files file, like so:`test = import_viscosity_data(7)`

it works perfectly. But, when I issue the call from another file, like so: 

'new_list = load_files.import_viscosity_data(7)'

it returns None.

Comment: Yet your function returns `None`. *This indicates a bug in your code*. We cannot help you debug this without seeing your code.

Comment: Ok, I've added a bunch of information. I still think it's returning a reference to a list that's already been deleted, but I'm fairly new to the Python.

Comment: For the attribute error, I tried deleting the files in `__pycache__` (the pyc files), but it made no difference.

Comment: You probably have *another* module named `load_files` in your path. Does `print(load_files.__file__)` print the expected file location?

Comment: `print(load_files.__file__)` gives me just `.\load_files\__init__.py`

Comment: That is a package directory, **not** your `load_files.py` module. You have *two conflicting* import options, and python picked a different one from what you expected.

Comment: I don't understand. So load_files.py should NOT be in a folder named load_files?

Comment: Not if it is just a module. Otherwise, use `from load_files.load_files import test_func`.

Comment: And it seems I misdiagnosed, I thought you had both a `load_files` directory and a `load_files.py` file *side by side*.

Comment: Well now the import works if I use `from load_files import load_files`

Comment: Packages are otherwise **optional**. You do *not* need to create a package for every single module.

Comment: OK, well that resolves the secondary problem. Still don't know why I can't pass the list of lists from `load_files` to the other file. Can I use copy.deepcopy()?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was the `test.py` file's import statement. At first, I confused the issue by having, in the same directory as the `test.py`, `load_files.py` and also a directory called `load_files` which contained `load_files.py` as well as a blank file called `__init__.py`.

The original script read

```
import load_files
print(load_files.import_viscosity_data(7))
```

I eliminated the `load_files.py` which shared a directory with `test.py`. Now, I have `test.py` in the parent directory, then a sub-directory called `load_files` which contains `load_files.py`. The new script reads:

```
from load_files import load_files
print(load_files.import_viscosity_data(7))
```

Now, the list of lists is passed in to the local space, so a statement like

```
list_test = load_files.import_viscosity_data(7)
```

works fine.

I couldn't get things to work correctly when I just had the two `.py` files in the same directory (e.g. `test.py` and `load_files.py` in the same directory, no sub-directory). The import statement of `import load_files` threw an error that the module doesn't exist. Anyway, it all works well now with the above code.

Special thanks to Martijn Pieters for the feedback.